# Custom div loading not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To those jQuery experts out there.  I have the following markup and code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Framework</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.nav').click(function(e) {
        e.PreventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var path = "views/" + id + ".html";
        $("#main").load(path); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="links">
    <a class="nav" id="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Test Page</a>
</div>
<div id="main">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

<strike>My nav class fires when I click the link, but fails to get past the PreventDefault method.</strike> The class fires, but nothing loads into my div.  The page is definately there.  Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be with your call to preventDefault:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.nav').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var path = "views/" + id + ".html";
        $("#main").load(path); 
    });
});
```

Comment: The preventDefault case was the issue.  Thanks!